# gradle versions conflict and resolution

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies

I want to make sure how gradle dependencies were resolved in this case:

```
$ wget https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar/archive/refs/tags/6.13.7.tar.gz
$ tar -xf 6.13.7.tar.gz
$ cd Simple-Calendar-6.13.7/app
$ ../gradlew dependencies | grep "com.google.code.gson:gson:" | sort -u
     |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:{strictly 2.8.6} -> 2.8.6 (c)
```

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sec:conflict-resolution), it says that (emphasis mine)

> Maven will take the *shortest path* to a dependency and use that version

So in this case `2.8.6` won (right?) does this information exist in the web output? (with `--scan`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have quoted and emphasized is true for **Maven**. In the docs, it states the following for Gradle:

> Gradle will consider all requested versions, wherever they appear in the dependency graph. Out of these versions, it will **select the *highest* one.**

In your sample snippet, between GSON 2.8.0 and 2.8.6, 2.8.6 is selected because it is the highest version. In addition, there appears to be [strict version enforced](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version) since *strictly* appears in the snippet.

Comment: Oh I see ... thanks ! do you happen to know if the (nice !) web output contains info about the selected version?